# Sticking some elements to the left and others on the right while keeping it align on same line

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, footer

I've search every where, for hours, but never come across a solution.

In my footer, I want elements to stick to the left and others to the right when we see it on a screen 1024 px and over. I've tried to position:absolute AND left/right float but when I do so everything seem to collapse.

[How I wish it looked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6jgv.png)

[When I add float:right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYN6R.png)

```css
footer {
 background-color: #262524;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 2.4em;
 bottom: 0em;
 overflow: auto;
}
footer a {
 color: white;
}
footer a:hover  {
 color: #006AEC;
}
.contact {
 width: 1.3em;
 height: auto;
 margin-right: 1em;
 display: none;
}
footer div  {
 padding: 1em 0;
 color: white;
 font-weight: 200;
}
footer div ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.social {
 width: 2em;
 margin: 1em 0.3em;
 height: auto;
 display: inline;
}
.social:hover {
 opacity: 0.5;
}
.header {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding-top: 2em;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: white;
 display: block;
 width: 100vw;
 padding-bottom: 0.6em;
}
.copyright {
 background-color: #191919;
}
.copyright p {
 margin-top: 1em;
}
.gris {
 color: #999897;
}


@media (min-width: 1024px){
.inline  {
 padding: 0;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 24.6%;
}
.floatLeft {
 float: left;
}
.floatRight {
}
footer .inline {
 margin-right: 1em;
 margin-left: 1em;
 width: auto;
}
.right {
 text-align: right;
}
.droit {
}
.left {
 text-align: left;
}
footer {
}
footer .right {
}
.contact  {
 display: inline-block;
}
.header {
 text-align: left;
 padding-left: 1.6em;
}
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h6 class="header">Hince Transport</h6>
  <div class="inline floatLeft">
  <div class="inline left">
    <p> 634, Jolin Street,<br>
      Hearst, ON<br>
      Canada<br><br>
      
      P.O. Box 38<br>
      P0L 1N0
      </p>
  </div>
    
   <div class="inline left"><p>TOLL FREE <a href="tel:1-888-900-1658">1-888-900-1658</a><br><br>
   <img src="../images/icon-phone-full.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="contact"/><a href="tel:705-372-6111">705-372-6111</a><br>
   <img src="../images/icon-fax-full.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="contact"/>705-372-6110<br>
   <img src="../images/icon-email.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="contact"/><a href="mailto:ginoh@hincetransport.com">ginoh@hincetransport.com</a></p></div>
   </div>
 
 
  <div class="inline right floatRight droit">
   <ul class="inline">
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="team.html">Out Team</a></li>
     <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="involvement.html">Involvement</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="inline">
     <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="careers.php">Careers</a></li>
     <li><a href="rateRequest.php">Rate Request</a></li>
     <img src="../images/icon-facebook-white.svg" alt="" class="social"/>
      <img src="../images/icon-google-plus-white.svg" alt="" class="social"/></ul>
     
  </div>
  
  
  
<div class="copyright">
 <p class="gris inline floatLeft">This webpage developed with assistance by NEOnet Inc.</p>
 <p class="inline floatLeft">Created by <a href="http://mariepierld.ca">Marie-Pier LD Design</a></p>
 <p class="inline">© 2017 HINCE TRANSPORT. All Rights Reserved</p>

</div>
</footer>
```

PS: I'm sorry, my code is probably a mess. I tried a lot of stuff to make it work, and I'm not a developper.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `clear` property to make sure you are clearing floated elements. And you can also use `flexbox` to space elements evenly.

Add this CSS to your media query:

```
 .copyright {
    clear: both;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

More info:

[Float](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**snippet**

```css
footer {
  background-color: #262524;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2.4em;
  bottom: 0em;
  overflow: auto;
}

footer a {
  color: white;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #006AEC;
}

.contact {
  width: 1.3em;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 1em;
  display: none;
}

footer div {
  padding: 1em 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 200;
}

footer div ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.social {
  width: 2em;
  margin: 1em 0.3em;
  height: auto;
  display: inline;
}

.social:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  padding-bottom: 0.6em;
}

.copyright {
  background-color: #191919;
}

.copyright p {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.gris {
  color: #999897;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .copyright {
    clear: both;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .inline {
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 24.6%;
  }
  .floatLeft {
    float: left;
  }
  .floatRight {}
  footer .inline {
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    width: auto;
  }
  .right {
    text-align: right;
  }
  .droit {}
  .left {
    text-align: left;
  }
  footer {}
  footer .right {}
  .contact {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .header {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 1.6em;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <h6 class="header">Hince Transport</h6>
  <div class="inline floatLeft">
    <div class="inline left">
      <p> 634, Jolin Street,<br> Hearst, ON<br> Canada
        <br><br> P.O. Box 38<br> P0L 1N0
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="inline left">
      <p>TOLL FREE <a href="tel:1-888-900-1658">1-888-900-1658</a><br><br>
        <img src="../images/icon-phone-full.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="contact" /><a href="tel:705-372-6111">705-372-6111</a><br>
        <img src="../images/icon-fax-full.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="contact" />705-372-6110<br>
        <img src="../images/icon-email.svg" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="contact" /><a href="mailto:ginoh@hincetransport.com">ginoh@hincetransport.com</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="inline right floatRight droit">
    <ul class="inline">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="team.html">Out Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="involvement.html">Involvement</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="inline">
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="careers.php">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="rateRequest.php">Rate Request</a></li>
      <img src="../images/icon-facebook-white.svg" alt="" class="social" />
      <img src="../images/icon-google-plus-white.svg" alt="" class="social" /></ul>

  </div>



  <div class="copyright">
    <p class="gris inline floatLeft">This webpage developed with assistance by NEOnet Inc.</p>
    <p class="inline floatLeft">Created by <a href="http://mariepierld.ca">Marie-Pier LD Design</a></p>
    <p class="inline">© 2017 HINCE TRANSPORT. All Rights Reserved</p>

  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Flexbox isn't completely supported in all browsers - especially anything IE.

Comment: @Beepye I use Flexbox on production sites that need to support older versions of IE. Sometimes there are problems but they can generally be solved using workarounds. This is helpful list: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs  -- Like anything, it depends on the project

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks! But what are my problems in other browsers? And how do I work around?

Comment: @mariepierld_ Working for me in Chrome, Firefox, IE11 ... The only way to really know how your site looks across other devices / browsers is to test them.